# Using for loop variable to select tuple value (Python)

Tags: python

I'm creating a for loop in python to loop through values in a Tuple. The code I have is:

```py
for x in SageResult:
    SOPOrderReturnID=SageResult[x]
```

This produces the error:

```
InsertError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Replacing `x` with `0` works fine, but using the loop value doesn't work. How can I get around this?

Comment: What part of error you could not understand? Try `print(type(x))` inside your loop

Comment: `for x in SageResult:
    SOPOrderReturnID=x`

Comment: When you iterate over a list or whatever it is you didn't get an index, you get the corresponding value instead.

Comment: Noticeably, if `SageResult` is a `tuple`, this code will be equivalent to `SOPOrderReturnID = len(SageResult) - 1` or `SOPOrderReturnID = SageResult[-1]` (depending on what was originally wanted) because only the last assignation will survive the loop.

Comment: Using first `range` and then indexing makes no sense. Just use what @ncica answered in the first code block

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this case, loop on indexes, not on data.

```
for x in range(len(SageResult)):
    SOPOrderReturnID=SageResult[x]
```

Answer (score 3):

`for x in SageResult:` iterates through the tuple and writes every element of the tuple to `x`. So you should write this inside the loop:

`SOPOrderReturnID=x`

But if you want to work with tuple's indices, you should use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) function:

```
for index, x in enumerate(SageResult):
    SOPOrderReturnID=SageResult[index]
```

or [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range):

```
for index in range(len(SageResult)):
    SOPOrderReturnID=SageResult[index]
```

Comment: Both enumerate and range are unnecessary here if all you need is to access the element which is directly given by `x`.

Comment: It is why I wrote the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in SageResult:
     SOPOrderReturnID=x
```

Or:

```
for x in range(len(SageResult)):
     SOPOrderReturnID=SageResult[x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `x` is not an integer. I assume you could rewrite the loop in the following:

```
for x in range(0, len(SageResult)):
```